# Heroku Application Error: Page Could Not Be Served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am getting the notorious H10 error code when I deploy my rails app to Heroku. I am able to run the app fine on localhost in both development and production environments, but the app crashes on the Heroku server, and for the life of me I cannot figure out why. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Here is the Heroku log output:

```
2014-05-09T17:41:54.182987+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.182991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183000+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183037+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183039+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183044+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183046+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183048+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183073+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183004+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183032+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183035+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183075+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183081+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183083+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183085+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183087+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183089+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183091+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183094+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183095+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183098+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183105+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183107+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183109+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183111+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183114+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183116+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183120+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183137+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-05-09T17:41:54.183144+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-05-09T17:41:55.497609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-09T17:41:55.477865+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-05-09T17:42:20.351071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=gym-buddy.herokuapp.com request_id=338088e2-cd48-4e03-b86d-f10affcc1fe6 fwd="50.161.122.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-09T17:43:09.850563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=gym-buddy.herokuapp.com request_id=c8aabac5-40d9-4280-ae09-f98e732d5aec fwd="50.161.122.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-09T17:43:10.096915+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=gym-buddy.herokuapp.com request_id=d7f811bc-552b-468f-bad6-b64cc6c2b7d0 fwd="50.161.122.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-09T17:47:17+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-09T17:47:27+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-05-09T17:47:28.378988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-05-09T17:47:27.663397+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 3d09657 by arweiner@alumni.stanford.edu
2014-05-09T17:47:27.663498+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v24 created by arweiner@alumni.stanford.edu
2014-05-09T17:47:34.782209+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-09T17:47:34.782056 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-05-09T17:47:32.436199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 49930 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786681+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786682+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786684+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:2:in `<class:ContactController>'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786690+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786679+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786668+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': No such file to load -- User (LoadError)
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786692+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786698+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786695+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786701+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786706+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786711+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786720+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786725+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786715+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786716+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786722+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786737+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786730+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786790+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:4:in `require'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786792+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786793+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786795+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786796+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786797+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786802+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `call'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `build_app!'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786806+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786808+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786809+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786738+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786733+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786741+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786745+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786746+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786749+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786751+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786789+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786787+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
2014-05-09T17:47:38.786728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-05-09T17:47:40.340920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-09T17:47:41.711243+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=gym-buddy.herokuapp.com request_id=ca9aae56-ee44-4725-89d0-f4d108922e1a fwd="50.161.122.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-09T17:47:41.947708+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=gym-buddy.herokuapp.com request_id=7aff3d6f-2687-4aa2-affd-590a3cea1b57 fwd="50.161.122.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-09T17:47:40.329886+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [dev/prod parity](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/development-configuration#dev-prod-parity) thing.

How do you run your code locally?  Do you run it via `bundle exec`?  My suspicion is you have local problems (perhaps dependency problems) that you're not seeing because your local app is actually broken but not being run properly locally (but of course, this is a guess on my part).

Comment: I am running my app locally via the WEBrick server that comes bundled with rails. I can run my app on the rails server in both development and production environments (i.e. passing the -e production flag to the rails s command). It is possible that I am having dependency problems; however, no errors are reported in the rails log output, so I am not sure how I would go about identifying such an error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you run it locally with `bundle exec`?  Or do you just run it with `rails s`?  You should run it with `bundle exec` - that should probably manifest the dependency problem locally, if you have one.

Comment: I ended up opening a ticket with the Heroku support team. Apparently, I was having a file loading issue. The app was working locally because of Rails' lazy loading. I fixed the issue by removing a require statement, and now the app is running on Heroku again. Thanks for your comments.